# Laravel Vite doesn't work in DEV mode out of the box

Tags: laravel, vite

I can't figure out what's happening with Vite in the DEV development mode. In this mode, all incoming CSS and JS files aren't being compiled, which means the JS code itself doesn't work at all, including the code that comes bundled with Laravel out of the box. After launching in DEV mode, an error appears in the console: 'GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/bootstrap net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)'. All of this has been tested on a freshly installed copy of Laravel 10.2.9 and by running the commands 'npm i & npm run dev'. However, everything works as expected after the BUILD process.

Run: npm run dev

Ater starting vite in DEV mode no any assets (scss & js) compiled, so page doesn't work correctly:
`GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/bootstrap net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`